# Shutdown dialog only appears after about 30 seconds in GNOME while using Caffeine extension

Tags: 17.10, shutdown, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, caffeine

When I want to shutdown my PC I click the top right corner and then press the power button after which a dialog pops up with the options: power off, restart, cancel.

Normally this pop up shows up right away. But since a week or so it takes about 30 seconds. During that time I can move my mouse but I can't open applications or do anything else.

When I cancel and try it again, it does open right away.

I didn't change settings or install weird stuff, only some updates of my icon theme. (I apparently had installed the [Caffeine extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/)).

What could be the cause? And how can I diagnose this issue and see what it taking so long?

Comment: Do you have Caffeine extension enabled?

Comment: I do have installed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine/issues/48) in the [Caffeine extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/) which causes GNOME shell to temporarily stop responding on first power button event. Disabling the extension should get rid of the issue.

As a replacement you may use another extension called [Keep Awake!](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1097/keep-awake/) which provides similar (but with fewer options) functionality or wait (or hope) for the Caffeine extension to get updated with a fix.

Alternatively you may install the Caffeine application instead of the extension by running

```
sudo apt install caffeine
```

Comment: The keep awake extension did crash my gnome shell.

Comment: @TristanT Works fine here (although in an Xorg session, not the default Wayland session), try rebooting/relogging-in after installing the extension.