# GNOME shutdown dialog taking too much time to appear

Tags: shutdown, 20.04, gnome-shell

When I select the '*Power Off* / *Log Out*' option from the top bar and then select the '*Power Off...*' option, the shutdown dialog (the one that adds a gray overlay to desktop) is taking something like 5 to 30 seconds (randomly) to appear.

I have these GNOME Shell extensions active:

- Blyr
- Clipboard Indicator
- Impatience
- Keep awake!
- NetSpeed
- NoAnnoyance

The problem is present when all of them are disabled. The problem persists on both Xorg and Wayland.

What could be possibly the cause and how can I fix it?

*Update:* I get this error in journal when trying to shutdown:

```
Failed to load the backend: Failed to execute statement 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF': file is not a database
```

and when the dialog appears:

```
Failed to get update info from PackageKit: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: @pomsky I have these extensions active: Blyr, Clipboard Indicator, Impatience, Keep awake!, NetSpeed, NoAnnoyance

Comment: And the problem is present when all of them are disabled

Comment: Okay, so this not the same as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005745/480481) then.

Comment: If you log into a different user account (temporarily create one if need be) and try shutdown from there, does it work properly there?

Comment: @heynnema No, Other users also are affected

Comment: In `terminal` type `sudo shutdown -h now` to shutdown, or `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot, and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: @heynnema These commands shutdown my laptop instantly and without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a software named PackageKit, and the database of this software was corrupted, leading to this error. I fixed it using the commands from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059223/packagekit-database-disk-image-malformed):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge packagekit
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

(Other symptoms include getting this at the end of every single apt command: `Error: timeout was reached`)